# KIP-500: Replace ZooKeeper with a Self-Managed Metadata Quorum

Tags: apache-kafka

Hello folks we need to have a status about KIP-500: Replace ZooKeeper with a Self-Managed Metadata Quorum
and if there is any way to thest this use case regards 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-500%3A+Replace+ZooKeeper+with+a+Self-Managed+Metadata+Quorum

Comment: The best place to ask about a KIP is on the Apache Kafka dev mailing list: https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@kafka.apache.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KIP-500 has been voted by the community.

However, as described in the KIP (emphasis mine):

> **This KIP expresses a vision** of how we would like to evolve Kafka in
>   the future.  We will create follow-on KIPs to hash out the concrete
>   details of each change.

At the moment, Kafka still requires Zookeeper. By voting this KIP, the community only agreed that the dependencies on Zookeeper should be removed, it's a plan/vision.

As mentioned in the KIP, quite a lot of work is required to make this a reality. Future KIPs will be created to define that needs to be done. Some of that work has started but there's still a lot to do.

This means that at the moment there's nothing you can test.

To keep up to date, I suggest you regularly check the [dev mailing list](http://kafka.apache.org/contact). There was also a great session about this work at the last Kafka Summit: https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-san-francisco-2019/kafka-needs-no-keeper